# VS Code debugger toolbar buttons disabled during debugging session

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner C programmer. Currently, I have Visual Studio version 1.61 September 2021 installed
on my windows 64-bit system. I also installed MingW64 and set up the environment variables to compile and debug with the purpose of writing, debugging and running my c programs.

I have been able to write and run my programs without any issues. I did notice that whenever I wish to debug my program, the debug toolbar that hovers on top has the buttons disabled and no line is pointed by the "yellow arrow".

I modified the "launch.json" file where I set the following:

```
"stopAtEntry": true,
```

This set the yellow arrow to point at the beginning of the program instead of the breakpoint and the debug toolbar buttons were activated. Though whenever I step-over on to the next line of code, the yellow arrow disappears and the debug toolbar buttons are deactivated once again.
This happens often on lines where I assign values to variables.

I am a beginner and I find VS Code quite frustrating, I would appreciate your input and suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I solved it.

So it turns out that there is nothing wrong with my debugger and it was behaving as it should. I noticed that it would always fall into that behavior whenever the gcc compiler was to execute the line including `scanf()`. The registers and variables in the watchlist would suddenly become "unavailable" this is because the compiler was waiting for user input.

Since VS Code did not show the running program on PowerShell, I modified the "launch.json" certain configurations to the following:

```
 "externalConsole": true,
```

This allows for Command Prompt to open up, display the running program and allows for user input.

Once the user input is received the debug toolbar buttons are activated again and I could continue debugging. The watchlist variable also become available to analysis.

```
"stopAtEntry": false,
```

I set this configuration to false because I did not wish for the debugger to begin at the beginning of the program.

This was certainly frustrating but after finding the solution to this "issue", I bet that my endorphin and oxytocin levels are off the charts.

Very thrilling, this is what I love the most about problem solving.

Comment: Great to see you solved your problem. However, you did not need to set `"externalConsole": true`. If you keep it as false, the integrated terminal is used which IMO is more convenient. You might want to try that out

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the suggestion